# Should we explicitly define a language hint for Dart code blocks?

Tags: discussion, edits, syntax-highlighting

Google Code Prettify currently does not support syntax highlighting for the Dart language (no wonder why). Currently there are already few questions (and answers) about Dart which contain code blocks. As they are not highlighted, would it be right to edit them and explicitly specify an other language (`lang-javacript` seems to provide the best highlighting options for Dart code)? Like this:

`<!-- language: lang-javascript -->`

Or it would be better to leave them as is and wait until Google Code Prettify author adds a support for the Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be nice to support every programming language but that's not reasonably possible. I just tried the code blocks with **Ada** and it does not highlight the code properly either. I don't think we should jump on the **Dart** bandwagon just yet. I'd imagine there would have to be some overwhelming evidence that this would be beneficial and not a waste of time for yet-another-programming-language.