# Add default syntax highlighting for the [dart] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I just approved several edits from a user adding [explicit syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) to questions with the [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) tag. Apparently [since this was last discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109089/should-we-explicitly-define-a-language-hint-for-dart-code-blocks), Google Code Prettify has added support for Dart.

I suggest it's time to follow suit and update the default syntax highlighting associated with the [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) tag. Adding it manually to every question sounds like way too much work, even if I all I have to do is click the "Approve" button.

Comment: Been meaning to raise this request myself. =)

Comment: Any updates on this? Any way this can be set by tag wiki owners?

Comment: Hmmm, [revision 12 in "Syntax highlighting language hints"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/75019/revisions) seems to suggest even *explicitly* adding the language hint is not supported?

Comment: @Arjan Perhaps the problem is that the developers have not updated our version of Prettify to the latest?

Comment: Okay, Cody, so then *"several edits from a user adding explicit syntax highlighting to questions with the dart tag"* implies people are preparing for future enhancements? (By adding `<!-- language: lang-dart -->` while that doesn't do anything yet?) Or did you mean they are adding the JavaScript hint instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming to you live on Stack Overflow... highlighting support for [dart] and [erlang].

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to MSO?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Meh. Plugin support applies to other sites that have syntax highlighting enabled. And I don't care to shuffle old questions around for the sake of perfect categorization.

Comment: Yeah, but it's clearly about very specific tags which exist only on Stack Overflow. Anyway, meh indeed. Thanks! :)