# Enable automatic syntax highlighting for VHDL

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

VHDL is a [language supported by Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Could the [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl) tag have `<!-- language: lang-vhdl -->` associated with it by default?

It appears that [others have this concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133261/list-of-languages-for-syntax-highlight?rq=1#comment369631_133277) too.

---

VHDL syntax highlighting doesn't appear to be working.  Should it be?

`lang-vhdl.js` was listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/191029), but it doesn't work automatically with [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247955) tagged as [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl), or manually when I specify `<!-- language: vhdl -->`.

Comment: @balpha I removed the `<!-- language:` from the question and the syntax appears to be working correctly, automatically now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening in the first case, using `<!-- language: vhdl -->`, is that you're requesting the default syntax highlighting associated with the [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl) tag (which shouldn't even be necessary, since the question already has that tag). Since you're not getting what you expect when you do this, it stands to reason that there is no default syntax highlighting specified for this tag.

When you change the syntax highlighting hint to `<!-- language: lang-vhdl -->`, you're explicitly requesting syntax highlighting for VHDL, *regardless* of the question's tags and overriding the default.
It's just as if you'd specified `<!-- language: lang-java -->`: you'd start getting Java syntax highlighting, even though it would be useless and nonsensical for the code blocks in that question. It is, however, useful for questions and answers that are liable to have code blocks in multiple supported languages (e.g. C# and VB.NET).

So the solution here is to get a moderator to update the syntax highlighting associated with the [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl) tag. (Assuming that my diagnosis is correct; I can't check what the default syntax highlighting for a particular tag is, but moderators can.)

Comment: "So the solution here is to get a moderator to update the syntax highlighting associated with the [tag:vhdl] tag." -- Done.

Comment: If you're playing then there's [Dart](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172966/add-default-syntax-highlighting-for-the-dart-tag) and [MATLAB](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language), which are both supported by Prettify but not SE @balpha.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Neither of the two are supported by Prettify. There are Prettify *plugins* for them.

Comment: Okay, terminology wrong but SE supports other Prettify plugins and could do the same for others (I assume?). Though, obviously makes it harder if you don't have them at the moment.